# query executed successfully but did not return number of rows SSMS 18.3.1

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-18

Executing simple select statement does not displays the number of rows returned.

It show `"Query executed successfully"` but do not show how many rows returned.

[image]

Comment: what's your query?

Comment: select top 100 * from myTable

Comment: it shows how many row returned !.what are those results? :)

Comment: Just updated.  It shows for me.  Perhaps the window extends beyond the display boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the **Messages Tab** right next to the Results Tab.

Should say something like `(100 rows affected)`

Comment: You are right. I got used to it shows on a side. Is any way to move it into result Tab?

Comment: Not that I know of, try maximizing the SSMS window.

Comment: The row count in the query results status bar is unrelated to the rowcount (sometimes) sent to the client through TDS.  IE if you `set nocount on` you'll still see the rows in the result status bar.

Comment: You can affect how this information is displayed, here's an article about it: https://www.ssmstipsandtricks.com/blog/2014/06/23/customize-editor-tab-and-status-bar/

Answer (score 3):

The row Count in status bar is displaying by default, just be sure its flag is on.

you can check it form next navigation:-

`Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `Editor Tab and Status Bar`.

[image]

Comment: It set to True by default. But still does not display in a result tab

Comment: It was for me too, but I changed it to false and then true and then clicked ok.
Fixed issue for me, not sure if it will work for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but Ahmed had most of the answer. For me I had to set the "Include row count" to false" first. Then the other normal status results began to show. Setting it back to true returned the row counts.